# Angular Text swap with color, Cordova, Onsen

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, text

So i have a simple text and image swap using angular in Cordova with Onsen framework.

```
<p ng-class="{'green_text': is_fan_on}">
     {{is_fan_on ? 'FAN ON' : ''}}
</p>
```

and my css

```
.green_text {
    color: #00ca26;
}
```

my click event

```
$scope.toggle_fan = function(){
    $scope.is_fan_on = !$scope.is_fan_on;
}
```

everything works great except for iPhones. There is a single line of pixels remnant from the previous text. check this out

[image: Fan is on with image and text correct]
[image: Fan is off with proper image and text remnant]
[image: Fan is off with text and remnants]

dosnt matter the text, the colors, FAN OFF text, nothing

w/e color and words are there during start up and its color, stay there when switching

Android phones, emulators, chrome dev tools - all those phones work fine. Switches with no problems. THIS IS ONLY ON IPHONES

i am running the app using CLI - phonegap serve onto my personal iPhone6 and the problem is apparent on the physical device

I am also running iphone emulators with cordova and the problem is also apparent there (thats where the images came from)

All work done on MAC computer.

I have current Xcode, cordova, angular....

is this a bug? am i doing something wrong? this seems simple and ridiculous IMO...

Answer (score 0):

I had

```
line-height: 1;
```

in my CSS for compatibility across devices.

Removing line-height normalization will fix the issue - but now you cannot set line-height..... so not really a fix